# How can I convert date from yyyy-mm-dd to mm-dd-yyyy in julia

Tags: julia

I want to change the format of the dates. I have column DATETIME in which the dates are arranged in YYYY-mm-dd format, I have to change the format to mm-dd-YYYY in julia.
name of the dataframe df1, column nate DATETIME.

Comment: Julia doesn't seem to support mm-dd-YYYY format as described in the documentation : https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/stdlib/Dates/#Dates.ISODateFormat . However, if you only need to display the date you certainly could convert a date to a String.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that you want to go from a string to a string (since a `Date` object in Julia doesn't have a specific format). You can (i) parse the string to a `Date` object, then (ii) format as a string in your desired way:

```
julia> using Dates

julia> str = "2021-12-03";

julia> date = Date(str, dateformat"yyyy-mm-dd")
2021-12-03

julia> Dates.format(date, dateformat"mm-dd-yyyy")
"12-03-2021"
```